# move from the search field to cell in jupyter notebook without clicking

Tags: macos, search, jupyter

How can I move the cursor from the search field (CMD F) to the first found item in Jupyter notebook without clicking in MacOS?

CMD Gs cycles through the found items, but the cursor and focus stays in the search field.

I tried tab, shift+tab and control+tab but none of them moved the cursor/focus to the first found item like I expected and wanted.

thank you.